# How to pass dynamic value in threshold for Alarm in Grafana dashboard for EKS Monitoring

Tags: nodes, grafana, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer, grafana-alerts

I want to use a dynamic value for calculating threshold for setting up an alarm on Grafana dashboard(EKS Monitoring).

I wish to calculate average count of concurrent connections per Node/GPU. Is there any way/metrics to calculate this ?